# Error when trying to build nextjs using React-Leaflet (T3 stack)

Tags: next.js, react-leaflet

I have some trouble trying to integrate **react-leaflet** with nextjs. I use dynamic import when I use the map in my **index.tsx** file. This works fine when I run the application using "pnpm dev / run", the problem arises when i try to build the application. When using "pnpm build" it compiles just fine but when it's on the step "collecting page data" it crashes and returns and error, the compleete log is below:

**Log**

```
$ pnpm build

> tjenesteplattform@0.1.0 build C:\Users\OlavA\OneDrive\Desktop\Tjenesteplattform
> next build

info  - Loaded env from C:\Users\OlavA\OneDrive\Desktop\Tjenesteplattform\.env
warn  - Invalid next.config.js options detected: 
  - The root value has an unexpected property, styledComponents, which is not in the list of allowed properties (amp, analyticsId, assetPrefix, basePath, cleanDistDir, compiler, compress, crossOrigin, devIndicators, distDir, env, eslint, excludeDefaultMomentLocales, experimental, exportPathMap, generateBuildId, generateEtags, headers, httpAgentOptions, i18n, images, modularizeImports, onDemandEntries, optimizeFonts, output, outputFileTracing, pageExtensions, poweredByHeader, productionBrowserSourceMaps, publicRuntimeConfig, reactStrictMode, redirects, rewrites, sassOptions, serverRuntimeConfig, skipMiddlewareUrlNormalize, skipTrailingSlashRedirect, staticPageGenerationTimeout, swcMinify, trailingSlash, transpilePackages, typescript, useFileSystemPublicRoutes, webpack).

See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/invalid-next-config
info  - Linting and checking validity of types .warn  - The Next.js plugin was not detected in your ESLint configuration. See https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint#migrating-existing-config
info  - Linting and checking validity of types
info  - Creating an optimized production build
info  - Compiled successfully
info  - Collecting page data ...ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at C:\Users\OlavA\OneDrive\Desktop\Tjenesteplattform\node_modules\.pnpm\leaflet@1.9.3\node_modules\leaflet\dist\leaflet-src.js:230:19
    at C:\Users\OlavA\OneDrive\Desktop\Tjenesteplattform\node_modules\.pnpm\leaflet@1.9.3\node_modules\leaflet\dist\leaflet-src.js:7:66
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\OlavA\OneDrive\Desktop\Tjenesteplattform\node_modules\.pnpm\leaflet@1.9.3\node_modules\leaflet\dist\leaflet-src.js:10:3)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at 5194 (C:\Users\OlavA\OneDrive\Desktop\Tjenesteplattform\.next\server\pages\Estate\ReactMap.js:223:18)

> Build error occurred
Error: Failed to collect page data for /Estate/ReactMap
    at C:\Users\OlavA\OneDrive\Desktop\Tjenesteplattform\node_modules\.pnpm\next@13.1.1_biqbaboplfbrettd7655fr4n2y\node_modules\next\dist\build\utils.js:960:15 {
  type: 'Error'
}
info  - Collecting page data . ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.
```

**ReactMap.tsx**

```
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
import {
    MapContainer,
    TileLayer,
    useMapEvents,
    Marker,
    Polyline,
    WMSTileLayer
} from 'react-leaflet';
import { useState } from 'react';
import L, { LatLng } from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility/dist/leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility.css';
import 'leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility';
import { getEstateInfo } from '../../server/api/norkart';
import { EstateInfo } from '../../types';

const isServer = (): boolean => typeof window === 'undefined';

const markerIcon = new L.Icon({
    iconUrl: './marker.png',
    iconRetinaUrl: './marker.png',
    iconAnchor: [32, 64],
    iconSize: [64, 64]
});

const LocationMarker = () => {
    const [position, setPosition] = useState<LatLng>();
    const [estateInfo, setEstateInfo] = useState<EstateInfo>();

    useMapEvents({
        click(e) {
            setPosition(e.latlng);
            getEstateInfo([e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng]).then((data) => {
                setEstateInfo(data);
            });
        }
    });

    return position === undefined ? null : (
        <div>
            <Marker position={position} icon={markerIcon} />
            {estateInfo && estateInfo.Geometri && (
                <Polyline
                    pathOptions={{
                        color: 'purple',
                        opacity: 1,
                        fillColor: 'black',
                        fillOpacity: 0.5
                    }}
                    positions={estateInfo.Geometri}
                />
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

const Map = () => {
    if (!isServer()) {
        return (
            <div>
                <MapContainer
                    center={[58, 8]}
                    zoom={12}
                    style={{
                        height: '100vh',
                        borderRadius: '5',
                        position: 'relative'
                    }}
                >
                    <TileLayer
                        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                        url='https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
                    />
                    {false && (
                        <WMSTileLayer
                            layers='webatlas-orto-newup'
                            url='https://www.webatlas.no/maptiles/wms'
                            maxZoom={21}
                            minZoom={19}
                            attribution='&copy; 2023 Norkart AS/Geovekst og kommunene/OpenStreetMap/NASA, Meti'
                        />
                    )}
                    <LocationMarker />
                </MapContainer>
            </div>
        );
    }

    return null;
};

export default Map;
```

**Index.tsx**

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
import { type NextPage } from 'next';
import Head from 'next/head';
import React from 'react';
import { Container } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import styles from './index.module.css';
import LandingPage from './LandingPage';

import { colors } from '../styles/Theme';

const Home: NextPage = () => {
    const MapNoSSR = dynamic(() => import('./Estate/ReactMap'), { ssr: false });
    return (
        <>
            <Head>
                <title>Create T3 App</title>
                <meta name='description' content='Generated by create-t3-app' />
                <link rel='icon' href='/favicon.ico' />
            </Head>
            <main className={styles.main}>
                <Container
                    backgroundColor={colors.white}
                    maxW='80%'
                    p={20}
                    borderRadius={3}
                >
                    <LandingPage />
                    <MapNoSSR />
                </Container>
            </main>
        </>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem for the same stack, and my map components were side-by-side with the page component. `next dev` worked fine, but `next build` failed.
NextJS collects some **page data** during the last build step and the solution for me was to move out my map components with disabled SSR **out from the pages** folder, for example to the dedicated **components** folder.
That helped with the build.

Comment: I forgot about the post until now, but this is correct, this is exactly how i solved it as well, thanks for the answer! :)